# strange temporary shorting

Tags: analog

I was testing a board of mine. I was testing the boards for any shorts. I have 3 Voltage planes 12V,5V and 3.3V.
I was using a multimeter in the connectivity/short mode to test if the Vcc and GND are shorted or not.
I have seen a strange behaviour. I connected the 2 probes of the multimeter to GNDs. So it has a long beeping noise which denotes a short(and is right).
Then I connected one of the probes to a non GND pin and it shows a short(1sec) beep and then silent.

What is this phenomenon. And what can be the causes of this pls.

Comment: What happens if you hold the multimeter (in right polarity) to a (big) capacitor?

Comment: I connected it to a 1000uF and its silent. No short.

Comment: Now discharge the cap (short its leads) and try again. Beep?  The "temporary short" is likely to be the decoupling caps charging.

Comment: I have 2000uF capacitors in my board. I think its the capacitor charging up and thinking its short initially. Hmmmmm

Comment: @VinodKaruvat: was it empty? at least with my multimeter it beeps for a short time before the cap is filled. Maybe yours outputs more power, try with a resistor that is low enough to let the multimeter beep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience a short blip often means that there is a diode drop from where you're measuring to ground or something similar, if you switch the probes around then the blip won't happen (in the case that it is a diode).

If your multimeter has a digital display it might display the voltage required to get the diode / component to start conducting and hence 'short' it to ground.

I've had this many times when testing and debugging circuits with lots of transistors / diodes.

As a side note as well, if you have some very small resistances in the circuit (>10-20 ohms) then the multimeter might also show that up as a short.

Comment: Yes . I have erers and many transistors and MOSFETs in my circuit.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat If you swap round the probes does the blip still happen?

Comment: yes it does @MrPhooky

Comment: @VinodKaruvat well it might be that your probes aren't polarised or something - that would be my guess

Comment: Also,when I do this test between the main Vcc and GND it shows 464Ohms. How can that be. Should it not show infinite impedance.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat Well there must be something in the circuit between Vcc and GND that has that resistance - a circuit diagram might be of use in this instance.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat, Try measuring the resistance to ground when the board is not powered. If you are measuring these values when the board is operating then your transistors may falsely show you low impedance to ground.